# Does the described subset of a metric space have an empty interior?

Tags: general-topology

Taken from "Introduction to Topology", by Gamelin and Greene:
Consider the metric space (ms) $(C([0,2]),\rho)$ of continuous, real-valued functions f on the interval [0,2] with the metric of uniform convergence. Let $E_m$ be the subset of f belonging to C for which their exists an x in [0,1] that satisfies $$\mid{\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}\mid}\leq m$$ for $t\gt0$, $x+t\leq2$.

On the question of whether $E_m$ has an empty interior or is nowhere dense (nowd), I looked at whether any function g(x) contained in the open ball $B(f;\rho)$ belongs to $E_m$ when f belongs to $E_m$.  If $E_m$ is nowd, then the answer should be no, as I understand.   Estimating the numerator of the fraction above for the function g, I find $$\mid{g(x+t)-g(x)}\mid \leq{\mid{g(x+t)-f(x+t)\mid}+\mid{f(x+t)-f(x)\mid}+\mid{f(x)-g(x)\mid}}$$  Because f is continuous on [0,2], the second term of the estimate may be arbitrarily small with t.  The first and third terms are arbitrarily small because $\rho$ may be small. Thus $\mid{g(x+t)-g(x)}\mid$ is bounded by $\mid{f(x+t)-f(x)}\mid$ which is less than m|t|.  Thus g belongs to $E_m$ and the latter is not nowd.  Where is my error?

Comment: The most we can say about the middle term on the RHS is $\exists x\in [0,1]\;\forall t\in (0,2-x]\;(|f(x+t)-f(t)|\leq mt,$ and the most we can say of the other RHS terms is that they are each less than $\rho$, so we have $|g(x+t)-g(t)|<2\rho +mt$ .

Comment: Related : Q # 2298837.

Comment: Then I gather I have shown  $E_m$ is nowd, admittedly unaware.